# Java Stack Overflow has been tormenting me for ages

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I just joined this wonderful community, but it is with regret that I admit that my first post ever here, has to do with a painful bug. While I was doing my **homework**, a brickbreaker oop uni project, I came accross a variety of bugs. The story so far:

- I had to create an abstract Brick class that inherits JButton functionality, that supports an abstract method, I call it brickSpecialAction(), to be implemented by the various brick subclasses (joker brick, shuffle brick, colour brick).
- I also had to create a Grid class that inherits JFrame and adds the board functionality for the game, and extends the functionality to changing levels each time the user has no available moves, and exceeds the score threshold, acting like an ActionListener for everytime I press one of the bricks and so forth
- Along with those classes, I have some minor classes, like Levels, that support the game, but don't do anything dramatic, or anything that has to do with the bug so far.
- **Where the bug comes from:** During the making of the first subclass of Brick, the ColourBrick, a brick that has some Background Color, I had to provide implementation for the brickSpecialAction method, that will be called by the listener class (Grid) everytime I press a brick of that type. Now at first, that method tormented my poor soul with a null pointer exception. After some further studying and improvements upon the code, I came up with a solution, that seamed viable, but in reality served only as a greater source of confusion: It did not execute properly and it left me with a StackOverflowError at hand.

**The classes so far:**

**The basic brick class**

```
package gr.teicrete.epp.ooplab.brickbreaker;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Point;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 * The Brick class will provide general functionality to our bricks.
 *
 * @author Fokis
 */
public abstract class Brick extends JButton{

    private Point brickPosition; // The brick's position
    private Container cont;

    /**
     * The Brick constructor used to initialize the bricks. Not really used as
     * we cannot instantiate the brick class, being abstract and such.
     *
     * @param posx The brick's x position
     * @param posy The brick's y position
     */
     public Brick(int posx, int posy) {
        this.brickPosition = new Point(posx, posy);
        this.setVisible(true);
     }

     /**
      * The public accessor method to the brick's position
      * @return The brick's position
      */
      public Point getBrickPosition() {
         return this.brickPosition;
      }

     /**
      * The public accessor method to the brick's container.
      *
      * @return The grid's container.
      */
      public Grid getContainer() {
         return (Grid) this.cont;
      }

      public abstract int brickSpecialAction(Brick brickie);
 }
```

The basic ColourBrick class:

```
package gr.teicrete.epp.ooplab.brickbreaker;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * The ColourBrick class provides functionality to the colourful bricks.
 *
 * @author Fokis
 */
 public class ColourBrick extends Brick {

/**
 * The constructor used to initialize our colour bricks.
 *
 * @param posx The x position of the brick. Used for indexing later.
 * @param posy The y position of the brick. Used for indexing later.
 * @param seed The seed to the random number generator, so as to pick
 * colours available at each level.
 */
public ColourBrick(int posx, int posy, int seed) {
    super(posx, posy);
    this.setBackground(this.pickColour(seed));
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 44));
}

/**
 * Public method used to initialise our bricks with a colour.
 *
 * @param seed the initial seed we provide to the random number generator
 * @return The color of the brick to be initialized.
 */
 public Color pickColour(int seed) {

    Random randomColour = new Random(); // A random object, for RNG
    Color assignedColor; // Used to store the color we picked

    int potentialColour = randomColour.nextInt(seed); // Picking a random num

    switch (potentialColour) {
        case 0:
            assignedColor = Color.RED;
            break;
        case 1:
            assignedColor = Color.CYAN;
            break;
        case 2:
            assignedColor = Color.GREEN;
            break;
        case 3:
            assignedColor = Color.YELLOW;
            break;
        case 4:
            assignedColor = Color.PINK;
            break;
        case 5:
            assignedColor = Color.MAGENTA;
            break;
        case 6:
            assignedColor = Color.BLACK;
            break;
        case 7:
            assignedColor = Color.ORANGE;
            break;
        case 8:
            assignedColor = Color.GREEN;
            break;
        default:
            // Not really needed, but we provide it to ensure that the compiler
            // won't argue that assignedColor might be uninitialized
            assignedColor = null;
    }
    return assignedColor;
}

/**
 * The method used to destroy the bricks that we click on.
 *
 * @param brickie Used for the recursive calls of the method.
 * @return The total number of bricks destroyed.
 */
@Override
public int brickSpecialAction(Brick brickie) {

    int totalRemovedBricks = 0; // Used to calculate the total number of removed bricks

    this.setVisible(false); // Making it invisible
    totalRemovedBricks++; // Counting it as a brick destroyed, in order to calculate the score later

    Grid omnigrid = (Grid) this.getTopLevelAncestor();
    Point brickPosition = this.getBrickPosition();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                // Checking to see if the brick above the one we have now has the same colour as the one we are in now
                if (omnigrid.getBrickByXAndY(brickPosition.x, brickPosition.y + 1).getBackground().equals(this.getBackground())) {
                    totalRemovedBricks += brickSpecialAction(omnigrid.getBrickByXAndY(brickPosition.x, brickPosition. y + 1));
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                // Checking to see if the brick beyond the one that we have now has the same colour as the one we are in now
                if (omnigrid.getBrickByXAndY(brickPosition.x, brickPosition.y - 1).getBackground().equals(this.getBackground())) {
                    totalRemovedBricks += brickSpecialAction(omnigrid.getBrickByXAndY(brickPosition.x, brickPosition.y - 1));
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                // Checking to see if the brick on the left of the one we have now has the same colour as the one we are in now
                if (omnigrid.getBrickByXAndY(brickPosition.x - 1, brickPosition.y).getBackground().equals(this.getBackground())) {
                    totalRemovedBricks += brickSpecialAction(omnigrid.getBrickByXAndY(brickPosition.x - 1, brickPosition.y));
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                // Checking to see if the brick on the right of the one we have now has the same colour as the one we are in now
                if (omnigrid.getBrickByXAndY(brickPosition.x + 1, brickPosition.y).getBackground().equals(this.getBackground())) {
                    totalRemovedBricks += brickSpecialAction(omnigrid.getBrickByXAndY(brickPosition.x + 1, brickPosition.y));
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    return totalRemovedBricks; // returning the total ammount of bricks destroyed used to calculate the score later
}
}
```

And the Grid Class:

```
package gr.teicrete.epp.ooplab.brickbreaker;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 * The Grid class will provide objects that will be used as our board for the
 * game.
 *
 * @author Fokis
 */
 public class Grid extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private Levels currentLevel; // A reference to the current level
private int generalHiscore; //  A variable storing the current HiScore
private float currentScore = 0.0f; // A variable storing the current Score
private int levelsElevated = 1; // A variable used to store the levels the player has elevated each time
private boolean changed;
private String playerName; // A variable used to store the current player's name

/**
 * The Grid constructor. Pretty much handles everything. From initialising
 * player score to filling the grid with bricks.
 *
 * @param playerName The current player's name.
 */
public Grid(String playerName) {
    super();
    this.currentLevel = new Levels(levelsElevated);
    this.generalHiscore = 0;
    this.currentScore = 0;
    this.playerName = playerName;
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(currentLevel.getLevelRows(), currentLevel.getLevelColumns()));
    initialize();
    pack();

    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setTitle("Player name: " + playerName + " Current Score: " + currentScore + " Hiscore: " + currentLevel.getHiScore()); // To be reviewed.
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(Grid.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

/**
 * The method that will be invoked everytime we need to change the level
 *
 * @return Whether or not the method was successful.
 */
public boolean changeLevel() {
    levelsElevated++;
    this.currentLevel = new Levels(levelsElevated);
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(currentLevel.getLevelRows(), currentLevel.getLevelColumns()));
    return true;
}

/**
 * The method that will be invoked everytime we need to see if the game
 * should change level, or if the player lost.
 */
public void checkState() {
    if (hasAvailableMoves() == false && isAboveScoreThreshold() == true) {
        changed = changeLevel();
    } else if (hasAvailableMoves() == false && isAboveScoreThreshold() == false) {
        System.out.println("What a pity. You lost.");
    }
}

/**
 * The method that will be used to calculate the score.
 *
 * @param removedBricks The total number of bricks removed each time. Used
 * to actually calculate the score.
 * @return The player's current score.
 */
public float calculateScore(int removedBricks) {
    if (removedBricks <= 4) {
        currentScore += removedBricks;
    } else if (removedBricks >= 5 && removedBricks <= 12) {
        currentScore += (removedBricks * 1.5);
    } else {
        currentScore += 2 * removedBricks;
    }

    if (currentScore > currentLevel.getHiScore()) {
        currentLevel.setHiScore(currentScore);
    }

    return currentScore;
}

/**
 * The method that will be used to check if the player is above each level's
 * winning score threshold.
 *
 * @return The current state of the player's score.
 */
public boolean isAboveScoreThreshold() {
    if (currentScore >= currentLevel.getLevelRequiredScore()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * The method that will be used to check if the player has available moves
 * left. Will later be used to check whether or not we should change level.
 * NOT YET IMPLEMENTED.
 *
 * @return Whether or not the player has available moves left
 */
public boolean hasAvailableMoves() {
    return true;
}

/**
 * The method that will be invoked everytime we need to parse one of the
 * bricks.
 *
 * @param x The x position of the brick
 * @param y The y position of the brick
 * @return The brick that we want to manipulate.
 */
public Brick getBrickByXAndY(int x, int y) {
    return (Brick) this.getContentPane().getComponent((y * this.currentLevel.getLevelRows()) + x);
}

/**
 * The method that will be invoked to actually fill our Grid with bricks.
 */
public void initialize() {

    int acceptedBricks; // To be used for calculation of acceptedBricks

    for (acceptedBricks = 0; acceptedBricks < currentLevel.getLevelTotalBricks(); acceptedBricks++) {
        for (int x = 1; x <= currentLevel.getLevelRows(); x++) {
            for (int y = 1; y <= currentLevel.getLevelColumns(); y++) {
                Brick newBrick = new ColourBrick(x, y, currentLevel.getLevelAvailableColours());
                newBrick.addActionListener(this);
                this.add(newBrick);
                acceptedBricks++;
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    Brick brickClicked = (Brick) evt.getSource();
    calculateScore(brickClicked.brickSpecialAction(brickClicked));
    this.setTitle("Player name: " + playerName + " Current Score: " + currentScore + " Hiscore: " + currentLevel.getHiScore());
    this.checkState();
}
}
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** I am not so cheap as to ask others for a solution to the project or the problem, I just want someone to explain to me why I have this error. After that I am gonna try to solve this alone. But please help me. I have tried hard already.

**EDIT:** The stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.awt.Component.isVisible_NoClientCode(Component.java:1288)
    at java.awt.Component.isVisible(Component.java:1285)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setVisible(JComponent.java:2639)
    at gr.teicrete.epp.ooplab.brickbreaker.ColourBrick.brickSpecialAction(ColourBrick.java:90)
    at gr.teicrete.epp.ooplab.brickbreaker.ColourBrick.brickSpecialAction(ColourBrick.java:101)
    at gr.teicrete.epp.ooplab.brickbreaker.ColourBrick.brickSpecialAction(ColourBrick.java:101)
    at gr.teicrete.epp.ooplab.brickbreaker.ColourBrick.brickSpecialAction(ColourBrick.java:101)
    at gr.teicrete.epp.ooplab.brickbreaker.ColourBrick.brickSpecialAction(ColourBrick.java:101)
    at gr.teicrete.epp.ooplab.brickbreaker.ColourBrick.brickSpecialAction(ColourBrick.java:101)
    at gr.teicrete.epp.ooplab.brickbreaker.ColourBrick.brickSpecialAction(ColourBrick.java:101)
    at gr.teicrete.epp.ooplab.brickbreaker.ColourBrick.brickSpecialAction(ColourBrick.java:101)
    at gr.teicrete.epp.ooplab.brickbreaker.ColourBrick.brickSpecialAction(ColourBrick.java:101)
    at gr.teicrete.epp.ooplab.brickbreaker.ColourBrick.brickSpecialAction(ColourBrick.java:101)
    at
```

and it keeps on like this for freaking ever.

Comment: Each time you get an exception in Java, it comes with a stack trace which allows finding exactly where this exception comes from. Show us this stack trace. We won't read all your code and try to guess where the exception comes from. In general, error messages are intended to be read.

Comment: Love the for loop that iterates through all cases of the switch statement, might want to eliminate the loop and the switch and just write the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is occurring because you check to see if the block above you is the same color, and if so repeat the same logic, and that logic is checking to see if the block below is the same color, if so repeat the same logic.  So if a block on top is the same color as a block on bottom it is bouncing back and forth until you get a stack overflow.  Maybe remove the blocks as you check them, or make some flag to signify they are already flagged for removal and change the logic to check for that and not infinitely re curse.

I'm guessing there's other issues with your code, but this might get you past your current error...

```
public int brickSpecialAction(Brick brickie) {

    int totalRemovedBricks = 0; // Used to calculate the total number of removed bricks
    if (!this.isVisible)    //Or whatever you can check to see if you have set this invisible already
        return;             // You've already executed on this block
    this.setVisible(false); // Making it invisible
```

Answer (score 2):

Your brickSpecialAction() method contains calls to itself.  Without proper controls, this puts you into an infinitely recursive loop.  StackOverflow errors are frequently caused by such situations.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is definitely the recursion in brickSpecialAction()

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) is, conceptually, very similar to what you're trying to accomplish.